# electron error The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: angular, electron

I'm trying to add electron to my angular project, but running the electron command I get the error 
The system cannot find the path specified, the path is: ng build --base-href ../ && electron
[image: my index.html is located in src/app]
and it looks like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SchoolReportMaker</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>



  <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

any help will be appreciate!